# Installation of 3rd party package in Python

Tags: python

How can i Install the 3rd party package in python.?
I have setup.py file in 3rd party package.

I need to know steps involved and how to do?
Where to write the commands and how to actually do it.

Comment: I know the command for it.
python setup.py install
Where to write this command and how to give path.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), and [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 1):

"python setup.py install" - http://docs.python.org/install/index.html

Comment: im writing python setup.py install
and its giving syntax error

Comment: import sys
sys.path.append ("c:/.../setup.py")
python setup.py install

but Im facing syntax erroe

Comment: @user1481676 - What are you trying to install? Can you copy and paste the complete error message into your comment?

Comment: I have my package installed in d:\
in python command line i am writing

import sys
sys.path.append("d:/../setup.py")
python setup.py install

but its showing the filw handle error and syntax error

what shud i do?

Comment: I'm afraid my python has been from Linux, but a few things that stick out: A - If this is in a DOS prompt, shouldn't those slashes '/' be backslashes'\'? B - If in cygwin, shouldn't it be "/cygdrive/d/myPath"? C - "d:/.."? You want to go one directory down from the root?! Windows isn't going to like that at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work:

```
pip install <path to folder>
```

Also highly recommend using virutalenv or/and zc.buildout

Comment: import sys
sys.path.append ("c:/.../setup.py")
python setup.py install

but Im facing syntax erroe

Comment: Sry, I have no knowledge dealing with python on widows :/.